# Loop to count number of rows in each column and save output

Tags: r

I think this is pretty simple. I have a dataframe called df. It has 51 columns. The rows in each column contains random integers. All I want to do as a loop is add all the integers in all the rows of each column and then store the output for each of the columns in a seperate list or dataframe.
The df looks like this

```
Col1 col2 col3 col4
  34    12    33    67
  22      1    56    66
```

Etc

The output I want is:

```
 Col1 col2 col3 col4
   56    13   89  133
```

I do want to do this as a loop as I want to apply what I've learnt here to a more complex script with similar output and I need to do it quick- can't quite master functions as yet...

Comment: Check out `?colSums`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built in function `colSums` for this:

```
> df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,2,3), col2 = c(2,3,4))

> colSums(df)

col1 col2
   6    9
```

Another option using a loop:

```
# Create the result data frame
> res <- data.frame(df[1,], row.names = c('count'))

# Populate the results
> for(n in 1:ncol(df)) { res[colnames(df)[n]] <- sum(df[n]) }

col1 col2
   6    9
```

Comment: Guess I'm looking for a loop so I can apply it more generally to the more complex script too

Comment: I have added another option to the answer, using a for loop. Is this something like you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a loop over a vectorized solution, use `apply` to loop over columns (second argument equal to `2`, `1` is to loop over rows), by mentioning the function you want (here `sum`):

```
df = data.frame(col1=1:3,col2=2:4,col3=3:5)

apply(df, 2, sum)

#col1 col2 col3 
#   6    9   12
```

Comment: And by the way, to use with a more complicated function, you can add an annonymous function in place of sum:

`apply(df, 2, function (i) {
    sum(i)
})`

Comment: No need for backets and this is useless to wrap sum in an anonymous function there.

Comment: Indeed, I actually typed it in more than one line, he might need the brackets if he does more than one operation. 
    `apply(df, 2, function (i) {
        m <- mean(i)
        s <- sd(i)
        s/d
    })`

Not that it can't be done in one line, but that's the idea.